# Ember action on a div with child anchor link

Tags: ember.js

I have a div with a click action on it, and inside the div I have a normal anchor tag going to a link
example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wiledaduwi/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<div {{action "actionClick"}}>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
</div>
```

Fortunately the action is firing, but the click on the anchor (and opening the link in a new tab) is not... Any suggestions?

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3911

Comment: This is similar to action within action/anchor within anchor.  It's generally considered bad practice (and for some circumstances not allowed).  You'd be better off changing your anchor tag to call an action, and then propagating that action if you need to catch it at a parent scope as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kingpin2k suggested in his comment, what I was doing was generally considered bad form and not following ember's convention.

I've also confirmed this in the #needshelp Ember Slack chatroom.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
     <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div>
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" {{action "actionClick"}}>google</a>
    </div> 
  </script>
```

and in actions:

```
actions: {
    actionClick: function() {
      window.console.log('Action click!!!');
      window.open('http://www.google.com');

    }
  }
```